# how to sanitize any request or any page

Tags: javascript, express, sanitization

i `m bulding a web app and i want to make sure that no one input a html or script tags so i use sanitize packacge but how to apply it on each input ?
i wonder what is the easiest way to sanitizeHtml the whole input from the user

i tried this code on index.js but it didnt work

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const body = req.body;
   sanitizeHtml(body);
   console.log(sanitizeHtml(body))
  next();
});
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not a useful problem description. What were you expecting it to do, what did it do instead?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem; why even accept arbitrary HTML from untrusted sources? What *exactly* are you trying to sanitize out? What's your threat model?

Comment: `body` could be read-only, normally what we do is create a `locals` variable inside the response and append stuff there, for example `res.locals = { body: sanitizeHtml(req.body) }` and for now on, never read `req.body` but `res.locals.body`...

Comment: @balexandre it didn`t work as a validator for the user`s input and it return an error (Cannot convert object to primitive value
)

Comment: remember that `req.body` is only available if you add middleware for [body parsing](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)